# Question: i've found a strange function that use an externally declared variable inside a cursor where clause

Tags: plsql

today i was looking to some old code and i found this function where a cursor have inside a variable in the where clause but this variabile was not assigned in the cursor statement itself but later in the code, just before opening the cursor.
I've sanitazed the function from company data:

```
create FUNCTION VERY_STRANGE_FUNCTION(
  input_field IN VARCHAR2,
  input_field_value IN VARCHAR2
   )
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
out_RESULT VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN
 DECLARE
    var_ID_ORDER   VARCHAR2(100);
    var_ID_ORDER_2 VARCHAR2(100);
    OUTPUT_VAR     VARCHAR2(4000);
    
    CURSOR cur_ORDERS IS
        SELECT ID, NAME, COMPANY
        FROM ORDERS
        WHERE ORDER_ID1 = var_ID_ORDER
          AND ORDER_ID2 = var_ID_ORDER_2;

BEGIN
    var_ID_ORDER := input_field
    var_ID_ORDER2 := input_field_value

    FOR rec IN cur_ORDERS
        LOOP
            OUTPUT_VAR := rec.COMPANY;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN (OUTPUT_VAR);
end;end;
```

Im new to PLSQL, but in all the courses i had take i see that if i need to create a cursor that need a variable i should do something like that:

```
CURSOR cur_dummy (var1 VARCHAR2, var2 NUMBER) 
IS
  select 
  ID,NAME,NUMBER 
  from ORDERS 
  where ID = var1 
    AND NUMBER=var2;
```

This is a correct way to mix cursors and variables or not? For me, the first thing i could think of, is that the cursor could not be cached or reused becouse every time is different.
This function is a lot more complex, about 3000 rows, add 10 cursors like that with joins from 10 tables each and get called about 100 times during some queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use `CURSOR` parameters. Your cursor SQL is able to reference any variable within its naming scope, which would include the immediate procedure, plus any package level variables if packaged.

When you *do* choose to use `CURSOR` parameters, you are adding a new, narrower naming scope in which you can have variables that have value *only* within the cursor and nowhere else. This can give cleaner code that is less liable to bugs like looping and opening a cursor in that loop without resetting procedure-level variables that the cursor depends on. A classic situation where this happens is when you have nested cursors and the results of the outer cursor and driving the inner cursor's parameters. Being forced to pass in what it needs helps prevent variable-setting bugs in situations like this.

But if you're not looping on the cursor open itself (just the fetching), there is really little reason to choose one over the other. Follow your programming style or your company's standards for style decisions like that.

Comment: Thanks Paul! i've never seen something like that during the courses in 6 month so for me was new and strange but you give me a big relief as that could will stay in production as is! :) thanks again and have a good day!